# Expected state of a Markov chain

Tags: probability, reference-request, markov-chains, markov-process

Let's start with a slightly trivial Markov chain defined as follows: the beginning state is called $1$ and the set of states is $\mathbb{N}$. At each step, when the current state is $n$, the probability the state changes to $n+1$ is $f(n)$ for some function $f: \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$ with $f(1) =1$. Otherwise the states remains unchanged.

To be more descriptive, the initial state is $1$. At the first step, the state changes to $2$ (with probability $f(1)=1$, so it always does). Then at the second step, the state changes to $3$ with probability $f(2)$ but otherwise stays there.

Call this first chain "chain 1". If one wants to know what's the expected value of the state after $k$ steps, there seems to be a trick:

- Let $T_{n,n+1}$ be the random variable for the time to go from state $n$ to $n+1$.
- Then $\mathbb{E}(T_{n,n+1}) = 1/f(n)$.
- Next, let $t_k = \mathbb{E} \big( \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} T_{n,n+1} \big) = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \mathbb{E}(T_{n,n+1}) $.
- Then $\mathbb{E}(X_{t_k}) = k$.

So it suffices to invert the function $k \mapsto t_k$ to get a good idea of the answer.

$\mathbf{Sub-Question:}$ Is there a name to the above trick? or a reference where this is done rigorously?

Now look at this other chain, called "chain 2". The initial state is $1$. Then, at each step, when the state is at $n$,

- the probability the state changes to $n+1$ is $w(n)$ for some function $w: \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$ with $w(1) =1$;
- the probability the state changes to $n-1$ is $l(n)$ for some function $l: \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$ with $l(n) < w(n)$ and $l(n)+w(n) \leq 1$;
- Otherwise the states remains unchanged.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is the expected value of "chain 2" (for $w$ and $l$ fixed) the same as the expected value of "chain 1" for $f(n) = w(n) - l(n)$.

Comment: "there seems to be a trick... $E(X_{t_k})=k$"... Where did you get this? It seems deadly wrong. To begin with, I would not know how to define $E(X_{t_k})$ when $t_k$ is not an integer.

Comment: I did not get it anywhere (I thought it up), that's why the sub-question asks for a reference where this is done, and, as you pointed out, I'm not pretending this is rigorous, which is why I'll be glad to have "a reference where this is done rigorously". As a first step, one should probably define the random variable $\tau_k = \inf_j \lbrace j \mid X_j = k \rbrace$. Then $\tau_k = \sum_{i = 1}^{k-1} T_{i,i+1}$. Next $k= \mathbb{E}(X_{\tau_k}) = \mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}(X_{\tau_k}\mid \tau_k) )$. PS: some numerics hint at the fact that the trick seems to give the right estimates.

Comment: See the answer below for some detailed explanations about the reasons why the comment above by the OP (and the question itself) does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to come up with a solution for what is equivalent to your first chain.

Let $P_{n,k}$ denote the probability that the Markov process is in state $k$ after $n$ timesteps, and let $p_k:=f(k)$ denote the probability to transition from state $k$ to the next. Notice that your first state, which is guaranteed to be transitioned in the first time step, can be omitted - the stochastic process starts afterwards. So we start with $P_{0,0}=1$.

You can easily see that the cases $P_{n,0}$ occur if the first transition has failed to happen $n$ times, so $P_{n,0}=(1-p_0)^n$.

We can approach all other cases ($k>0$) by identifying a recurrence relation, since for the process to be in state $k$ at time $n$, at time $n-1$ it must have either been in state $k-1$ and transitioned, or already in state $k$ and not. Therefore:

$$P_{n,k}=P_{n-1,k}*(1-p_k)+P_{n-1,k-1}*p_{k-1}$$

However, actually solving this recurrence relation turned out to be quite difficult for anything with $k>1$. When trying you'll notice a sum coming up that, after excluding all common factors, looks very similar to the multinomial theorem, but lacks any multinomial coefficients (i.e. all coefficients are equal to one). When you think about it this makes sense: Our total probability should be equal to the sum of the probabilities of all paths that lead to its position on a $(k\times n)$ grid. Each of these paths must contain the $k$ successful transitions and $n-k$ failures, the latter of which can occur at $k+1$ discernible positions with repetition, yielding ${{n-k+k+1-1}\choose{n-k}}={{n}\choose{k}}$ different paths, or summands in the emerging sum, respectively.

Nonetheless, it's possible to express this sum as one part of the factorization of a compact polynomial. After slicing it up and conducting numerous transformations, I discovered the following, rather compact solution:

$$P_{n,k}=\sum_{i=0}^k \left((1-p_i)^n*\prod_{j=1}^k \frac{p_{j-1}}{p_{(i+j)mod(k+1)}-p_i}\right)$$

So there you have it, with this you can calculate anything about chain 1. The expected state after $n$ timesteps you asked for, for example, is then given by:

$$E_n[K]=\sum_{k=0}^nk*P_{n,k}$$

Regarding your trick, I've used this as well and compared the results to numerically obtained exact solutions before I finished the compact formula. I agree that conceptually this should give a decent impression of roughly where the results are situated, but I suppose the performance of this approximation depends quite unpredictably on $f(k)$. In the example function I used, I did notice a systematic error in the results this gives, the error terms were diverging for larger $n$, albeit slowly. But with the given formula, this will no longer be necessary anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> Sub−Question: Is there a name to the above trick? or a reference where this is done rigorously?

No name, since the "trick" does not exist. A proper definition would include a definition of $E(X_{t_k})$ when $t_k$ is not an integer.

> Question: Is the expected value of "chain 2" (for $w$ and $l$ fixed) the same as the expected value of "chain 1" for $f(n)=w(n)−l(n)$.

No, for example $E_0(X_3)$ differs for chain 1 and for chain 2 when $w(n)=\frac12(1+f(n))$ and $l(n)=\frac12(1-f(n))$ for $0\leqslant n\leqslant 2$.

Comment: 1) Your counterexample is wrong, take $f(n)= 1$ for all $n$ then both chains do the same. 2) it was already clear that the answer to the question is no (see comments after Samrat Mukhopadhayay's answer). 3) the sub-question and the "trick" are to be taken *cum grano salis*. I'm looking for an argument which confirms or infirms the asymptotics given by the "trick".

Comment: "1) Your counterexample is wrong" ??? Sorry? "2) it was already clear" I know that, but, first I saw no clear argument in these comments, second the custom on this site (believe it or not) is to provide answers, not to force people to read full threads of comments to know what is going on. "3) the sub-question" This may be bad news but I stand by my answer: under the form explained in the question, there is no valid trick here.

Comment: Apologies, I did not mean to offense: simply explaining why I'm not voting up or choosing this as a valid answer... Here your answer to the sub-question is basically to take a question which is meant to be relatively vague and open in a word-to-word fashion and your answer to the question is giving an "example" (which turns out to have missing hypothesis) without details. I do believe a direct computation of $E(X_3)$ makes it readily clear, but somehow that's not really clearly written either in your answer. So: apologies again and thanks for your answer!